# How to remove duplicated rows in collection depending on two keys together

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have Database Collection, and i need to remove duplicated rows depending on two keys together

```
$messages = DB::table('users_mailbox')->where('msg_to', $username)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

I tried

```
$messages = $messages->unique('msg_from','ad_id);
```

This is my response

```
    +"id": 39
    +"ad_id": "2866527370"
    +"msg_from": "aliman"
    +"msg_to": "Haitham  Hmaserv"
    +"email": "amr@gmail.com"
    +"show_email": 1
    +"phone": "01002445900"
    +"show_phone": 1
    +"subject": "Re: akls;fdjl fa;dslkjf"
    +"message": "sadklfjlkads ;jfkladjf"
    +"is_read": 0
    +"created_at": "2020-03-15 00:15:53"
    +"updated_at": "2020-03-15 00:15:53"
```

But the result isn't correct.

Comment: I need to know what result of `$messages = DB::table...`

Comment: Hi you could use `GROUP BY` SQL clause, but I don't know how it converts in Laravel db dialect.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto 
        +"id": 39
        +"ad_id": "2866527370"
        +"msg_from": "aliman"
        +"msg_to": "Haitham  Hmaserv"
        +"email": "amr@gmail.com"
        +"show_email": 1
        +"phone": "01002445900"
        +"show_phone": 1
        +"subject": "Re: akls;fdjl fa;dslkjf"
        +"message": "sadklfjlkads ;jfkladjf"
        +"is_read": 0
        +"created_at": "2020-03-15 00:15:53"
        +"updated_at": "2020-03-15 00:15:53"
this is the response , i need to remove duplicated that have same ad_id and msg_from

Comment: @Amr It's only one row. Give the whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use multiple keys. `unique` only has 2 parameters,`$key` and `$strict`.

```
/**
 * Return only unique items from the collection.
 *
 * @param  string|callable|null  $key
 * @param  bool  $strict
 * @return static|\Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
public function unique($key = null, $strict = false)
{
    if (! is_null($key)) {
        return parent::unique($key, $strict);
    }

    return new static(array_values($this->getDictionary()));
}
```

You can pass your own callback to determine the uniqueness of the item :

```
$messages = $messages->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['msg_from'] . $item['ad_id'];
});
```

**Test**

```
array:10 [
  0 => array:13 [
    "id" => 1
    "ad_id" => "2866527370"
    "msg_from" => "Doe"
    "msg_to" => "Andy"
    "email" => "chet28@yahoo.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+1333054551110"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Nesciunt sed temporibus nulla quis ducimus."
    "message" => "Animi minus dolorem nostrum consectetur eos. Dolorum molestiae ea mollitia autem facilis numquam."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  1 => array:13 [
    "id" => 2
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Phil"
    "email" => "konopelski.bianka@hotmail.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+5618143199214"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Animi aut voluptas commodi quis."
    "message" => "Quisquam similique expedita quos vitae exercitationem omnis nostrum. Nesciunt aut ut rerum ex rem."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  2 => array:13 [
    "id" => 3
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Doe"
    "msg_to" => "Phil"
    "email" => "shaina92@gmail.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+8476237443387"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Et alias animi non vel repellendus."
    "message" => "Dolor eaque cupiditate aut omnis. Sed aut voluptatibus cupiditate consequatur."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  3 => array:13 [
    "id" => 4
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Doe"
    "msg_to" => "Natalia"
    "email" => "gabrielle86@hotmail.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+2733705925893"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Et earum et est voluptates voluptatibus rem."
    "message" => "Voluptas eum aut qui aut ex qui ipsa. Illo ea cupiditate est sunt qui iusto ut qui."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  4 => array:13 [
    "id" => 5
    "ad_id" => "2866527370"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Andy"
    "email" => "tracey.ledner@morar.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+5870383075455"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Sunt numquam et voluptatem pariatur quibusdam sit."
    "message" => "Ad possimus corrupti provident hic rem."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  5 => array:13 [
    "id" => 6
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "John"
    "msg_to" => "Natalia"
    "email" => "emilie08@yahoo.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+9398780932593"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Voluptates consectetur velit commodi deleniti."
    "message" => "Excepturi iste molestiae error qui."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  6 => array:13 [
    "id" => 7
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Andy"
    "email" => "reece.welch@yahoo.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+4309027792891"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Dolor consequatur mollitia sed numquam cupiditate."
    "message" => "Nisi alias non assumenda dolorem necessitatibus non."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  7 => array:13 [
    "id" => 8
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Phil"
    "email" => "santina.mosciski@morissette.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+7738160060411"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Iste at velit doloremque quas."
    "message" => "Vel error consequuntur incidunt sed nam itaque ut."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  8 => array:13 [
    "id" => 9
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Natalia"
    "email" => "kim.considine@gmail.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+7742196820229"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Praesentium repellat quod omnis."
    "message" => "Est et hic consequatur aut et omnis et. Sit perferendis et error eaque."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  9 => array:13 [
    "id" => 10
    "ad_id" => "2866527370"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Andy"
    "email" => "lane38@conroy.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+6448254479027"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Dolore velit aut perspiciatis."
    "message" => "Eligendi et eos harum magni quo pariatur porro. Non non qui quae voluptatum et laboriosam reiciendis."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
]
```

**Result**

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:13 [
    "id" => 1
    "ad_id" => "2866527370"
    "msg_from" => "Doe"
    "msg_to" => "Andy"
    "email" => "chet28@yahoo.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+1333054551110"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Nesciunt sed temporibus nulla quis ducimus."
    "message" => "Animi minus dolorem nostrum consectetur eos. Dolorum molestiae ea mollitia autem facilis numquam."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  1 => array:13 [
    "id" => 2
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Phil"
    "email" => "konopelski.bianka@hotmail.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+5618143199214"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Animi aut voluptas commodi quis."
    "message" => "Quisquam similique expedita quos vitae exercitationem omnis nostrum. Nesciunt aut ut rerum ex rem."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  2 => array:13 [
    "id" => 3
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "Doe"
    "msg_to" => "Phil"
    "email" => "shaina92@gmail.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+8476237443387"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Et alias animi non vel repellendus."
    "message" => "Dolor eaque cupiditate aut omnis. Sed aut voluptatibus cupiditate consequatur."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  3 => array:13 [
    "id" => 5
    "ad_id" => "2866527370"
    "msg_from" => "Aliman"
    "msg_to" => "Andy"
    "email" => "tracey.ledner@morar.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+5870383075455"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Sunt numquam et voluptatem pariatur quibusdam sit."
    "message" => "Ad possimus corrupti provident hic rem."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
  4 => array:13 [
    "id" => 6
    "ad_id" => "2866576390"
    "msg_from" => "John"
    "msg_to" => "Natalia"
    "email" => "emilie08@yahoo.com"
    "show_email" => 1
    "phone" => "+9398780932593"
    "show_phone" => 1
    "subject" => "Voluptates consectetur velit commodi deleniti."
    "message" => "Excepturi iste molestiae error qui."
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-22 04:19:54"
  ]
]
```

---

**I recommend you use `DISTINCT` instead of `unique` collection method.**